# how to call user-defined function of a window object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a function from outside which is defined with in a window object, but it throws an error.

```
    window.vcm = (function() {
    "use strict";
     function red(){
      alert('red');
     }   
   });  
  vcm.red();//Error at this line...
```

I am new to OOPS in javascript. Can somebody tell me how to call this function here.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches.

Approach 1 : 
    `window.vcm =  {
        red: function (){
            "use strict";
            alert('red');
        }
    };
    vcm.red();`

Approach 2 :

```
window.vcm = (function() {
    "use strict";
   this.red = function(){
      alert('red');
    }   
});
var x = new vcm();
x.red();
```

Answer (score 2):

The value that is `vcm` does not have a `red` property.

Perhaps you mean this instead, wherein `vcm` is an object that has a property `red` that is function you can call:

```
window.vcm = {
  red: function(){
    "use strict";
    alert('red');
  }   
};
```

It's also a possibility (albeit not somewhat you 'd see in practice) for `vcm` itself to be a function *and* for it to have a `red` property that is a function:

```
window.vcm = (function() {
  "use strict";
   var vcm = function() { alert("vcm"); }
   vcm.red = function() { alert('vcm.red'); };
   return vcm;
 })();

vcm();     // "vcm"
vcm.red(); // "vcm.red"
```

Answer (score 0):

`red` only exist inside the function you assigned to `window.vcm` and also only when the function is executed. Furthermore, functions don't have a property `red`.

Consider this simpler example:

```
function foo() {
    function bar() {}
}

bar(); // will throw an error
```

Calling `bar` will throw an error because `bar` is not defined in the scope where it is called.

It seems you want to assign an **object** to `window.vcm`, which has a property `red`:

```
window.vcm =  {
    red: function (){
        "use strict";
        alert('red');
    }
};
```

Here I am using an *object literal* to create an object with the property `red`.

More information:

- [MDN - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)